# Call OnCreate by pressing the backbutton

Tags: android

Hy!

My code:

```
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
        if (menuestate == 1)
            Main.this.onCreate(null);
        }
        }
```

if i press the backbutton i see the oncreate for a half second an then the homescreen occur

Whats wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to do exactly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not how it is supposed to work. If you want to restart your activity you need to call finish() and then restart it through the Intent, like this:

```
if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
{
    if (menuestate == 1)
        finish();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Main.this, Main.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```